# Laravel Backpack Login as Username and Password

Tags: laravel-backpack

I had Implemented Login Using "Username and Password" instead of "Email and Password" using **Laravel Backpack** in one machine and code was pushed to git, but When I had configured the same site in another machine using git then it is not working.Using Difference tool I have compared working copy and GIT (NOT Working Copy) and guess what... both are same.
I am bit confused why it is not working...

**Below is Version Information.**

Laravel Backpack for Laravel Version 5.4

Current Patch for changing login field from "email"=>"username"

in    app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php

```
protected $username = 'username'; // <=added
```

Comment: please contact us here https://gitter.im/BackpackForLaravel/Lobby

Answer (score 0):

please try code backpack login:

```
$user = Auth::user()->name;
```

Comment: I Don't have a field like a user, Instead of that I have used username and top of that ` Auth::user()->name ` can be used once we log in and the problem is I am not able to login into the application.